# Cake.Core.CakeException: The target 'commit' was not found

Tags: git, cakebuild

While committing the changes in git source via source tree, below error is shown during the execution of the cake script.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLoIh.png)

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the Cake file it tries to execute doesn't have a target named **commit**, which supplied to whatever launches Cake.

Only reason I would see cake executing during a commit would be if you have a commit hook triggering Cake.

Comment: Can you please share me the solution if possible?